# NetworkReply HttpStatusCode QVariant(Invalid)

Tags: qt, qt5, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply, qnetworkrequest

I'm using the code below to make a http request:

```
QNetworkReply* ApiRequest::req(QString url, QString method, QByteArray data) {
    QByteArray request_method = method.toUtf8();
    QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    QNetworkRequest request("http://127.0.0.1:9090" + url);
    request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    QNetworkReply* reply = manager->sendCustomRequest(request, request_method, data);
    return reply;
}

void ApiRequest::requestConfig()
{
    NetworkReply* reply = req("/configs",
        "GET",
        "");
}
```

The Remote server did execute the request and reply a 204 code.
I have used `wireshark` to capture and make sure it had reply a `204 No Content`.
However, the output there is `QVariant(Invalid)`, the `toInt` output is `0`.
I tried to change `PUT` to `GET` but it still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are analyzing the state even when the request has not been made so it is valid that the result is null, what you should do is analyze it when the finished signal is emitted:

```cpp
QNetworkReply* reply = mg->sendCustomRequest(request, "PUT", "....some json....");
connec(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [reply](){
    qDebug() << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);
});
```

Update:

```cpp
connec(mg, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, [](QNetworkReply *reply){
    qDebug() << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);
});
```

Update 2:

**Is there a way to return that reply when it is finished?**

Yes, use a QEventLoop, but in general it is a bad design since you should use signals and slots to notify you of the changes.

```
QNetworkReply* ApiRequest::req(const QString & url, const QString & method, const QByteArray & data) {
    QByteArray request_method = method.toUtf8();
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QNetworkRequest request("http://127.0.0.1:9090" + url);
    request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    QNetworkReply* reply = manager.sendCustomRequest(request, request_method, data);
    QEventLoop loop;
    connec(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
    loop.exec();
    return reply;
}

// ...

void ApiRequest::requestConfig()
{
    QNetworkReply* reply = req("/configs", "GET", "");
    // ...
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

Comment: If I want to return the manager when it is finished. How to do it?

Comment: I'm so sorry that I didn't explain it clearly. I have updated the code. Is there a way to return that reply when it is finished? Thank you :D

Comment: @Coel see the update. I have shown the solution but in general what you are trying to do is a bad design

Comment: Thank you so much for solving question. That helped a lot.

Comment: Sure. Thanks a lot for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

You can include QtNetworkReply and QEventLoop classes and use signal/slot mechanism.

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QUrl resource(url);
QNetworkRequest request(resource);
QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);
QEventLoop loop;
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
loop.exec();
QJsonObject jsonObject = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll()).object();
```